# Creating a constructor

Tags: methods, constructor

I've got some code I need help with. I'm an AP CS student (and it's introductory) so please don't judge me.

```
// name:  
    //
    // program:  CoinsTester
    //
    // purpose: 

    public class CoinsTester {



         public static void main(String[] args) {
     //create a new Coins object named money and pass it the amount of cents as a parameter
  //***** STUDENTS NEED TO COMPLETE ******
      Coins(); 
      Coins money = new Coins(); 

        // call the correct method in the Coins class to find your answer
  //***** STUDENTS NEED TO COMPLETE ******
        money.calculate(); 


    }

}



// name:  
//
// program:  CoinsTester
//
// purpose: This class accepts a certain number of monetary change.
//         The output is a list of the number of quarters, dimes, nickels,
//    and pennies that will make that amount of change with the least
//    number of coins possible.  This is a skeleton that will be finished 
//       by the students

    public class Coins {

 //private variable to store the only attribute of a "Coins" object - how many cents the 
 //    user wants to find change for. 
 private int myChange;

 //constructor that accepts an initial value for the private data member
 public Coins(int change) {
  myChange = change;
 } 

     // the method calculate will 
     // 1. use modular and regular division to determine the quantity of each type of coin
     // 2. prints the quantity of the coins needed to make the entered amount 
      public void calculate(){
      int quarters=25, dimes=10, nickels=5, pennies=1;
      int temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4; 
      int remainquar1, remaindime2, remainnick3, remainpenn4; 

        //variable declarations to hold the values needed for different coin types
        // make sure you use descriptive identifiers!
       //***** STUDENTS NEED TO COMPLETE ******

       // calculations for the various coin types
       //***** STUDENTS NEED TO COMPLETE ******


      // output statements, formatted as shown on specs  
       //***** STUDENTS NEED TO COMPLETE ******

      }   

     }
```

So here is the thing, I do apologize for my improperly formatted code. So when I run it, it says that Coins money = new Coins() cannot find a constructor for the code. I need help in creating a proper object. The thing here is that I have to create an object for "CoinsTester" then it tells me I have no constructor linked to the object. I really can't find solutions right now. Could someone just give me tips on how to create a constructor for the CoinsTester class?

Answer (score 0):

Add a "method" named CoinsTester (if you need a constructor for the class CoinsTester, it's not clear from your Q what constructor you need). Make sure the arguments correspond to the calling sequence, if you want the added explicit constructor to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You have two lines that need reviewing:

```
Coins();
```

This would call a method named Coins, not a constructor. I sugggest you remove this, as you most likely will not use/need it.

```
Coins money = new Coins();
```

The reason there is no constructor linked to this is that you already have a constructor for Coins:

```
public Coins(int change) {
    myChange = change;
}
```

When you created this constructor, you removed the default constructor **new Coins();**. If you'd like to be able to use the Coins constructor with no parameters, you can declare it again. Here's an example:

```
public Coins() {
    myChange = 0;
}
```

Comment: How would I declare it again? In CoinsTester or just Coins? Is it just re-declaring "public Coins() {
    myChange = 0;
} "

Comment: You would declare the public Coins() constructor in the public Class Coins. Then in your CoinsTester's Main method, you would just use the Coins money = new Coins(); line.